# Set Django JSONField value to a JSON null singleton with the Django ORM

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

Using a Django JSONField on PostgreSQL, say I have the following model

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.JSONField(null=False)
```

and I want to set a row to have `bar=null` where `null` is a single JSON null value (different to a database `NULL` value).

---

I can achieve it through a raw SQL query:

```
UPDATE "myapp_foo"
SET "bar" = 'null'::jsonb
WHERE "myapp_foo"."id" = <relevant_id>
```

---

The closest things I can do in the ORM is

```
Foo.objects.filter(id=<relevant_id>).update(bar=None)
```

but Django is interpreting this as a database `NULL` and I get the following error:

```
null value in column "bar" violates not-null constraint
```

or

```
Foo.objects.filter(id=<relevant_id>).update(bar="null")
```

but Django (correctly) interprets this as the JSON string `"null"`

---

Am I missing something or is this a gap in the ORM functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The Django docs have details about how to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#storing-and-querying-for-none

---

I have worked out this can be done with the Django `Value` class.

```py
from django.db.models import Value

Foo.objects.filter(id=<relevant_id>).update(bar=Value("null"))
```